# Google bigquery show all day count even if zero

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the below query to get the day wise count

```
SELECT date(timestampInterval), count(*) FROM `dataset.table`
WHERE DATE(timestampInterval) >= "2023-03-06"
group by 1
order by 1 desc
```

However if there is a date for which the count is zero, the results simply will not have it.
Is there a way to modify this query to include that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @gotqn mentioned, you need to generate dates filling up the whole period first. And then you can union them with the existing table to caluate a count for each day during the period without missing day.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH `dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '2023-03-06' timestampInterval UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-03-11' timestampInterval UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-03-13' timestampInterval
)
-- query starts here
SELECT date, COUNT(cnt) cnt FROM (
  SELECT DATE(timestampInterval) date, 1 cnt 
    FROM `dataset.table` WHERE timestampInterval >= '2023-03-06'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT date, null FROM (
    SELECT MIN(timestampInterval) min, MAX(timestampInterval) max 
      FROM `dataset.table` WHERE timestampInterval >= '2023-03-06'
  ),UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE(min), DATE(max))) date
) GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;

-- query result
+------------+-----+
|    date    | cnt |
+------------+-----+
| 2023-03-06 |   1 |
| 2023-03-07 |   0 |
| 2023-03-08 |   0 |
| 2023-03-09 |   0 |
| 2023-03-10 |   0 |
| 2023-03-11 |   1 |
| 2023-03-12 |   0 |
| 2023-03-13 |   1 |
+------------+-----+
```

Comment: what is date, 1 cnt? even if i change the number to 3 it works?

Comment: @JaangoJayaraj  yes, any not `null` value would work.  `COUNT(cnt)` will skip counting if `cnt` is null which means a day with no data.

Comment: For sure better/clear way to generate the date range. Would be good to have such functions in the other RDBS :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need use first to generate the dates. For example:

```
WITH date_range AS (
  SELECT DATE_ADD("2023-03-06", INTERVAL day DAY) AS date
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE("2023-03-06"), DAY))) AS day
)
SELECT date_range.date
FROM date_range
```

will gives you all days from the start date to today. Then join this CTE to your original table using `LEFT JOIN` and count the records the records again.